# Clarification needed in a insert query

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Table structure:

```
title { name varchar(100) }
```

If I try to insert a following query

```
insert into wikititle values('Men's');
```

I am getting an error quoted string not terminated properly.

Even if I use set escape on make it as

```
insert into wikititle values('Men\'s');
```

and inserted I am getting this error.

I am doing all these executions in oracle 11i sql plus.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Oracle, you need to double the quote:

```
insert into wikititle values('Men''s')
```

[Here is a link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ab1bd/1) to a test query on sqlfiddle.

Answer (score 1):

```
select q'{Men's}' from dual;
select q'|Men's|' from dual;
select q'"Men's"' from dual;
```